# What is the difference between these 2 sets?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have this question : 
The difference between {1,2,3} and {1,2,5} is :

1. {1}
2. {5}
3. {2}
4. {3}

Which one is the correct?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sets $A$ and $B$, $A-B$ is defined to be
$$
A-B=\{x|x\in A,\, x\not\in B\}
$$
The only number in $\{1,2,3\}$ that is not in $\{1,2,5\}$ is $3$, so the answer is $\{3\}$.

Answer (score 2):

It holds
$$\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace \setminus \lbrace 1,2,5\rbrace = \lbrace 3 \rbrace $$

Because you have to remove every element, that is in $\lbrace 1,2,5\rbrace$ from the set $\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace$. The $5$ is not in $\lbrace 1,2,3\rbrace$ so you just have to remove the $1$ and $2$, hence the result ist $\lbrace 3\rbrace$